# Change Azure VM role size using c#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I'm trying to replicate some PowerShell code to change the role size of an exising Azure VM by using the C# Management API (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute).

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
Get-AzureVM | Where-Object {$_.InstanceSize -ne 'Basic_A0'} | Set-AzureVMSize "Basic_A0" | Update-AzureVM
```

My C# code so far tries to downgrade a specific VM, but whenever I try to update the VM settings I get an exception that I don't really understand, as the PowerShell version does not need a ProvisionGuestAgent installed on the VM to change the role size.

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
>
> Additional information: BadRequest: In order to use extension
>   reference, ProvisionGuestAgent must be set during virtual machine
>   provisioning.

```
public void DowngradeVm(ComputeManagementClient Client, string VmName) {
  var hostedServices = Client.HostedServices.List();
  foreach (var service in hostedServices) {
    if (service.ServiceName != VmName) { continue;  }
    var deployment = Client.Deployments.GetBySlot(service.ServiceName, DeploymentSlot.Production);
    if (deployment != null) {
      if (deployment.Roles.Count > 0) {
        foreach (var role in deployment.Roles) {
          if (role.RoleType == VirtualMachineRoleType.PersistentVMRole.ToString()) {
            if (role.RoleSize != "Basic_A0") {
              // attempt do downgrade VM
              var upd = new VirtualMachineUpdateParameters();
              upd.AvailabilitySetName = role.AvailabilitySetName;
              upd.ConfigurationSets = role.ConfigurationSets;
              upd.DataVirtualHardDisks = role.DataVirtualHardDisks;
              upd.Label = role.Label;
              upd.OSVirtualHardDisk = role.OSVirtualHardDisk;
              upd.ProvisionGuestAgent = role.ProvisionGuestAgent;
              upd.ResourceExtensionReferences = role.ResourceExtensionReferences;
              upd.RoleName = role.RoleName;
              upd.RoleSize = "Basic_A0";
              // Service, Deployment and VM have the same name
              // the next line throws an exception
              Client.VirtualMachines.Update(VmName, VmName, VmName, upd);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Showing the C# code you have will be more helpful than just showing the PS you're trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: role.ProvisionGuestAgent was null (maybe because the role was not online), but needs to be true for the update to work.

```
          upd.ProvisionGuestAgent = true;
```